# Can a server offer more than one TLS certificate?

Tags: ssl, web-server, configuration, http, certificate

Let's say I have a TLS certificate for a domain but I'm not sure if all user agents potentially connecting over HTTP would accept it. Can I obtain another certificate, signed by another certificate authority, and use it in such cases as a fallback, transparently to the user? If it's possible, how would the client-server communication to establish a secure connection proceed? And is this use case well known and supported in configuration of popular HTTP servers?

I know there are similar questions but they ask about varying the used certificate by subdomain (possible) or path prefix (impossible IIUC because at negotiation time the server knows only the authority, not the full Request-URI).

Comment: I don't have a source for this, other than to state that I see many Cloudflare sites, especially, with both an EC and RSA certificate. I'm guessing the client is deciding which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a server offer more than one TLS certificate?

A server can *support* more than one TLS certificate. But it can only *offer* a single TLS certificate in the TLS handshake with the client. AFAIK that is the limit set in the TLS (handshake) protocol [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2)

The capability to *support* multiple certificates is most frequently  used when you have several different domain names that all point to the same server.

[Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)  sends the hostname of the server in the TLS handshake made by the client. That allows the server to select the best matching certificate to use for that connection.
I.e. the server can then use the certificate for `www.example.com` when the client indicates that it wants to connect to `www.example.com` and it can use a different (or default) certificate when the client is connecting with for example only the IP-address, no hostname or a different hostname in the ClientHello message.

In addition to the server name from the ClientHello TLS handshake message a server can be configured to use other parameters to select a different certificate.

For example when during the TLSv1.2 handshake the client indicates that the first preference is to use elliptic curves rather than RSA  , then an ECDSA key/certificate can  be offered and for clients that don't, an RSA certificate can be offered instead.
See for example https://www.haproxy.com/blog/serving-ecc-and-rsa-certificates-on-same-ip-with-haproxy/ and/or https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile

You can do the same with for example legacy clients that don't support ciphers above TLSv1.0

But once the certificate has been selected by the server, there is no fallback, the client either accepts or rejects the offered certificate.

Comment: [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46992) quotes RFC 5426, Section 7.4.1.1: "The HelloRequest message MAY be sent by the server at any time."
Can it be used to offer another certificate when the client has rejected the previously offered one?

Comment: It is difficult to send something though once the client has broken off the connection because it cannot validate the server certificate...